# Where does the serveHTTP utility come from on supposedly naked func

Tags: go, go-http

I have this utility:

```
type Handler struct{}

func (h Handler) Mount(router *mux.Router, v PeopleInjection) {
    router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/people", h.makeGetMany(v)).Methods("GET")
}
```

the above calls this:

```
func (h Handler) makeGetMany(v PeopleInjection) http.HandlerFunc {

    type RespBody struct {}

    type ReqBody struct {
        Handle string
    }

    return tc.ExtractType(
        tc.TypeList{ReqBody{},RespBody{}},
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
         // ...
    })
}
```

and then `tc.ExtractType` is like so:

```
func ExtractType(s TypeList, h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)  // <<< h is just a func right? so where does ServeHTTP come from?
    }
}
```

my question is - where does the serveHTTP method/func come from??

isn't the `h` parameter just a func with this signature:

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { ... }
```

so then how does that func have the `ServeHTTP` func attached to it?

In other words, why I am I calling

```
h.ServeHTTP(w,r)
```

instead of

```
h(w,r)
```

?

Comment: my only guess is that the core http or gorilla/mux lib magically adds that utility method after `http.HandlerFunc` gets returned to `router.HandleFunc`

Comment: I was not a fan of this adding function methods to a function pointer trick when I discovered it several years ago. Yes it is clever and all but I think it's confusing.

Answer (score 4):

The [http.HandlerFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) is a type represent `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)`.

The difference between `http.HandlerFunc` and `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)` is: `http.HandlerFunc` type has method called `ServeHTTP()`.

From the [source code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=59707:59754#L1950):

```
// The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of
// ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function
// with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a
// Handler that calls f.
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

---

The `http.HandlerFunc()` can be used to wrap handler function.

```
func Something(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // do something

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

The wrapped handler will have `http.HandlerFunc()` type, meaning we'll be able to access it's `.ServeHTTP()` method.

---

There is also another type, an interface called [http.Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler). It has `.ServeHTTP()` method signature, and it must be implemented on the struct where the interface is being embedded.

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

As you can see on `Something()` function above, a return value in `http.Handler` type is required, but we returned a handler wrapped in `http.HandlerFunc()`. It's fine, because the `http.HandlerFunc` has method `.ServeHTTP()` who fulfil the requirement of `http.Handler` interface.

---

> In other words, why I am I calling `h.ServeHTTP(w,r)` instead of `h(w,r)`?

Because to continue serve the incoming request, you need to call `.ServeHTTP()`.