# panic: Last argument needs to be of type http.HandlerFunc

Tags: go

I have this helper function, which is compiling fine:

```
func Middleware(adapters ...interface{}) http.HandlerFunc {

    log.Info("length of adapters:", len(adapters))

    if len(adapters) < 1 {
        panic("Adapters need to have length > 0.");
    }

    h, ok := (adapters[len(adapters)-1]).(http.HandlerFunc)

    if ok == false {
        panic("Last argument needs to be of type http.HandlerFunc") // ERROR HERE
    }

    adapters = adapters[:len(adapters)-1]

    for _, adapt := range adapters {
        h = (adapt.(AdapterFunc))(h)
    }

    return h

}
```

I am calling it like so:

```
router.HandleFunc("/share", h.makeGetMany(v)).Methods("GET")

func (h Handler) makeGetMany(v Injection) http.HandlerFunc {
    return mw.Middleware(
        mw.Allow("admin"),
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            log.Println("now we are sending response.");
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(v.Share)
        },
    )
}
```

the problem is that I am getting this error and I cannot figure out why:

> ```
>     panic: Last argument needs to be of type http.HandlerFunc
>
>     goroutine 1 [running]:
>     huru/mw.Middleware(0xc420083d40, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc42011f3c0)
>             /home/oleg/codes/huru/api/src/huru/mw/middleware.go:301 +0x187
>     huru/routes/share.Handler.makeGetMany(0xc4200ae1e0, 0x10)
>             /home/oleg/codes/huru/api/src/huru/routes/share/share.go:62 +0x108
> ```

it does confirm that the length of the adapters slice is 2:

```
 length of adapters:2
```

anyone know why that type assertion would fail in this case? Makes no sense. Maybe I am not actually retrieving the last argument of the slice or something? Is there a better way to pop the last argument off the slice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the 2nd argument of `mw.Middleware()` statement into `http.Handler` type by using `http.HandlerFunc()`.

```
func (h Handler) makeGetMany(v Injection) http.HandlerFunc {
    return mw.Middleware(
        mw.Allow("admin"),
        http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            log.Println("now we are sending response.");
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(v.Share)
        }),
    )
}
```

Comment: oh sweet jesus thanks I would have never figured that out

Comment: @MrCholo kindly please approve my answer if you think it solves your problem :-)

Comment: Yes, but why does it still *compile* even if you don't wrap the func in the http.HandlerFunc call?

Comment: It's because the `http.HandlerFunc` type is actually defined from `func(http.ResponseWriter,*http.Request)` type. Doc reference https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc

Answer (score 0):

In the http package, 
[ListenAndServe](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) has the following signiture

```
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error
```

where the `Handler` (i.e., `http.Handler`) is an interface

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

For one web application, there is only one `ListenAndServe` call, thus only one`handler`, which needs to deal with all the access points such as `/url1`, `/url2`, etc. If we write the `handler` from scratch, the implementation could be a custom `struct` that wraps around a database handle. Its `ServeHTTP` method checks the access point, and writes the corresponding content to the `ResponseWriter`, which is quite tedious and  mingled.

That's the motivation of [ServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux), which is the `router` in your code. It has a [ServeHTTP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux.ServeHTTP) method so it satisfies the `http.Handler` interface and can be used for `ListenAndServe`. In addition, it has the `HandleFunc` method to deal with the individual access point

```
func (mux *ServeMux) HandleFunc(pattern string,
                                handler func(ResponseWriter, *Request))
```

Note here the `handler` is not a `http.Handler`, i.e., it doesn't have `ServeHTTP` method. It doesn't have to because the `mux` already has `ServeHTTP` and its `ServeHTTP` method  can dispatch the individual access point request to the corresponding handlers.

Note it also has a `Handle` method, which requires the argument to satisfy the `http.Handler` interface. It's slightly less convenient to use compared to the `HandleFunc` method.

```
func (mux *ServeMux) Handle(pattern string, handler Handler)
```

Now back to your question, since you call `router.HandleFunc`, its input doesn't have to be `http.Handler`. So an alternative solution is to use `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)` as the return type for your middleware and `makeGetMany` method. (the type assertion in the middleware also needs to be updated, probably a lot more code needs to be updated as well)

@xpare's solution is to do type conversion so that all the function signatures match up, i.e., convert `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)` to `http.HandlerFunc`. It is also interesting to see how it works. From the [implementation](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=59707:59754#L1950)

```
// The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of
// ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function
// with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a
// Handler that calls f.
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

you can see that it basically defines a `ServeHTTP` method to call itself.